# permission with volume docker and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've created a docker-composer.yml file to run a container for wordpress mysql and phpmyadmin. It starts well bt i have a permission problem.  All my files have www-data:www-data for user and group and when i want to create a new theme in wp-content i have a permission denied. Im in ubuntu 18.04.

here is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
     - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

i tried to change to "chown -Rf myname:myname ." so there i can create a file but upload for files in wordpress doesn't work now. So i wonder how to set properly permissons with a docker mounted volume in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for this would be to add your own user `myname` to the `www-data` group

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data myname
```

and make sure the www-data group has write privileges on all files/directories and execute privileges on directories.

Another solution would be to let your own user own all files (`myname:www-data` as owner) and directories and make sure `www-data` group has appropriate read/write privileges so the WordPress container's webserver can use the group privileges to read/write files.

Off-topic: also make sure to have a

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

line in your `wp-config.php`.

Comment: i've added my user to www-data group but i still have this error. it was well added i checked with  "grep ^www-data /etc/group"
 and the return is www-data:x:33:myname

Comment: That's strange. Did you restart your shell after adding the user to the group? Usually, if the group has read/write access it should work fine.

Comment: Would you please share which one of two solutions you offered is preferrable and why?

Answer (score 1):

I just add `user: 1000:1000` to container, and everything works fine. Got idea from  [this tutorial](https://mklasen.com/adding-and-using-wp-cli-in-a-docker-compose-setup/)